# Typescript typeRoots priority

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-router, typescript-typings

I've redefined (extended) some class, loaded from npm, and appended types definitions, but for some reason my definitions have lower priority than the definitions from node_modules.

**Is it possible to manage the typescript definition priority using typeRoots property or whatever?**

An example:

I've imported `VueRouter` from `vue-router` package and extended it like that:

```
export class Router extends VueRouter {
  pushWithCheck (location: RawLocation): Promise<Route | void> {
    return this.push(location)
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        if (error && error.name !== 'NavigationDuplicated') {
          throw error
        } 
      })
  }
}
```

Then I created the file in `src/@types/vue.d.ts` with the following content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Router } from '../router'

export {}

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $router: Router
  }
}
```

Then updated `tsconfig.json` file, added `typeRoots: ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]` (tried in the reversed order as well).

That's what I see in vs code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The interface needs to be exported in *vue.d.ts* to have any effect:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  export interface Vue {
    $router: Router
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I placed vue.d.ts to every folder started with root, and on the root level (the same where tsconfig.json lives) it gives "Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property '$router' must be of type 'VueRouter', but here has type 'Router'." error. Maybe you are right, the folder somehow matters. Then I appended tsconfig.json with include: ["*.ts", ...] and everything returned back. Now when I right click on the $router, there're 4 definitions but the first is still VueRouter, but not any of mine.